# Node and Lazy: How do I know when it's done?

Tags: javascript, node.js, iasyncresult

I need to read a file line by line, and change a variable accordingly.
I would normally write this in PHP... but I decided to take the challenge.

I wrote:

```
fs = require('fs');
Lazy = require('lazy');
path = require('path');

files = fs.readdirSync('.');
var software = {};


files.forEach( function(fileName){


  var m; 
  if( m = fileName.match(/^(.*)\.txt$/) ){
    name = m[1];

    console.log("Processing file: " + fileName);
    software[name] = {};
    console.log("Software 1: %j",software);

    var section = 'unset';
    new Lazy(fs.createReadStream(fileName)).lines.forEach(
      function(line){
        var m;
        line = line + '';
        if( m = line.match(/^([a-zA-Z_]*):$/)){
          section = m[1];
          software[name][section] = '';
          console.log("Switching to section " + m[1]);
          console.log("Software 2: %j",software);
        } else if (line == '.'){
          section = 'unset'
        } else if (line == ''){
          section = 'unset'
        } else { 
          console.log("LINE: " + line) ;
          software[name][section] = software[name][section] + line + "\n";
          console.log("Software 3: %j",software);
        }
      }

    );   
  }

});

console.log("Software 4: %j",software);
```

Apart from the code being very ugly and very unoptimised, I am having trouble as when the last line prints, the "software" variable is not YET populated! I am guessing Lazy is asyncronous. So, it basically works, but "at some point later". This is great, but... where do I write code when that important cycle, that fills in the software variable, is actually finished?!?

As requested: data to play with!

simply create "something.txt" and write:

```
name:
Name 1
.

Option 1:
Value 1
.

Option 2:
Value 2
.

Option 3:
Multi
Line
Value
.

Another_section:
Again
.
```

Merc.

Comment: Good question! Could you give me some short example data to play with?

Comment: I mean, I *could* store fs.createReadStream(fileName)).lines.length and increase a counter for each line and then when the number of line is reached call a function... but it seems completely crazy to do. SURELY!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The instances of Lazy returned by the library are [EventEmitters](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html#events_class_events_eventemitter), and it emits en event called `pipe` when a "set" of operations is complete:

```
new Lazy(
  ...
).on('pipe', function() {
  // all done
});
```

Modifying your code to use this event results in (the only change is near the bottom):

```
fs = require('fs');
Lazy = require('lazy');
path = require('path');

files = fs.readdirSync('.');
var software = {};


files.forEach( function(fileName){


  var m;
  if( m = fileName.match(/^(.*)\.txt$/) ){
    name = m[1];

    console.log("Processing file: " + fileName);
    software[name] = {};
    console.log("Software 1: %j",software);

    var section = 'unset';
    new Lazy(fs.createReadStream(fileName)).lines.forEach(
      function(line){
        var m;
        line = line + '';
        if( m = line.match(/^([a-zA-Z_]*):$/)){
          section = m[1];
          software[name][section] = '';
          console.log("Switching to section " + m[1]);
          console.log("Software 2: %j",software);
        } else if (line == '.'){
          section = 'unset'
        } else if (line == ''){
          section = 'unset'
        } else {
          console.log("LINE: " + line) ;
          software[name][section] = software[name][section] + line + "\n";
          console.log("Software 3: %j",software);
        }
      }

    ).on('pipe', function() {
      console.log("Software 4: %j",software);
    });
  }

});
```

[Edit] To answer your question regarding how I found this info:

I did indeed check out [the source file for the project](https://github.com/pkrumins/node-lazy/blob/83afb5e6ab991237fe1a0ee4f0b2ac2961eb5cdf/lazy.js); I knew the library had a `sum` method that could be chained to instances of Lazy to sum up everything at the end; the [code for that method](https://github.com/pkrumins/node-lazy/blob/83afb5e6ab991237fe1a0ee4f0b2ac2961eb5cdf/lazy.js#L134-136) calls `foldr`, and the [code for that method](https://github.com/pkrumins/node-lazy/blob/83afb5e6ab991237fe1a0ee4f0b2ac2961eb5cdf/lazy.js#L123-132) listens for an event called `pipeName`, which is defaulted [in line 22](https://github.com/pkrumins/node-lazy/blob/83afb5e6ab991237fe1a0ee4f0b2ac2961eb5cdf/lazy.js#L22) as `pipe`.

Comment: I _have_ to ask... how did you find out?!? I read Lasy's docs, and didn't figure it out from there. THere isn't much in there in terms of "pipe" or "event" or "emit" either... I mean, how did you find this out? Did you have to dive into the source code?

Comment: Yeah, I agree the docs aren't very comprehensive; I greatly prefer `async` as my flow control library of choice. I've updated my answer with some additional info.

Comment: OK but my question stands... how did you find out?!? :D

Comment: @Merc: He added explanation to the end of his answer.

Comment: You mean how did I know it would be in there? Well, a flow control library that doesn't tell you when it's done isn't very useful, so I kind of made an assumption that something would be in there--besides, the chainable methods like `sum`, etc. wouldn't work in that case. It was just luck that the implementation was an event that [gets re-emitted](https://github.com/pkrumins/node-lazy/blob/83afb5e6ab991237fe1a0ee4f0b2ac2961eb5cdf/lazy.js#L29).

Comment: I'm getting instances of `pipe` firing before `foreach` is complete. I'm using `foreach` to read a file in, and modify specific lines, and then `pipe` to write back to the file. In some circumstances this results in either desired behaviour, a half empty file, or a totally empty file.

Comment: I tried https://github.com/nickewing/line-reader instead which seems much more purpose built and does not exhibit the race condition observed.