# Node lazy and async function in forEach

Tags: node.js, stream, lazy-loading

I try to read file with (aprox. 50 000 lines)  and save each line after parsing in mongodb. Mongodb save function is async. For iterating through a file I use node-lazy module.

What I get is that only a part of records saved in mongodb (save callback called not for all function)

```
var stream = fs.createReadStream(inputFile)

new lazy(stream)
    .lines
    .map(String)
    .forEach(function(line){
        db[collection].save(parseLine(line), function(err){

            if (err){
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                count++;
            }
        })
        }

)
```

So no errors, but count < actual records (lines) count;

So I wonder if what is the best way to fix the issue.

UPD:

I solved the problem by using syncronios parsing function in forEach and then when file is read fully, I saved data to mongodb with async.mapSeries.

But I still wonder is it possible to handle async with node-lazy, I didn't find it in docs, maybe it it just not possible.

Comment: How you verified that it is only half of records been saved?
As well could you verify that forEach is triggered required times?

Comment: I checked mongodb collection (in db). forEach is triggered required number of times. See my UPD.

Comment: Maybe you are too fast in Write operations. Google is silent about it. But there is possibility that there is a limit of how many writes you are trying to perform in too short period of time (in your case it is 50k writes).

Comment: Yes I can guess the possible root of the problem so I need to do writes sequentially to ensure correct behaviour. And what i'm asking is it possible to do with lazy forEach and async function inside of it.

Comment: You can create something like Promises in order to chain requests, or at least execute them in bulks.

Answer (score 0):

I know its months overdue but FYI someone answered this question here:

[Node and Lazy: How do I know when it's done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118169/node-and-lazy-how-do-i-know-when-its-done)